# Terraform internal libraries throwing errors for enable_classiclink

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm using terraform to create a multi-az RDS on AWS.  My .tf file shown below is a simple modification of a [hashicorp example](https://github.com/hashicorp/learn-terraform-rds).  When I do `terraform plan` I get these errors from terraform's internal libraries.  Nothing indicates a problem with my .tf files.

Any idea what could cause terraform's internal libraries to throw these errors?

--Edit--

I cloned the hashicorp repo above to a new location and I do not get the errors in that directory.  But when I copy the 4 .tf files to another directory and do `terraform init` and `terraform plan` the errors occur again.  It's as if terraform needs the .git directory or something else in the same directory.

Bizzare.

```
$ terraform plan
╷
│ Warning: Argument is deprecated
│ 
│   with module.vpc.aws_eip.nat,
│   on .terraform/modules/vpc/main.tf line 970, in resource "aws_eip" "nat":
│  970:   vpc = true
│ 
│ use domain attribute instead
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported argument
│ 
│   on .terraform/modules/vpc/main.tf line 36, in resource "aws_vpc" "this":
│   36:   enable_classiclink               = var.enable_classiclink
│ 
│ An argument named "enable_classiclink" is not expected here.
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported argument
│ 
│   on .terraform/modules/vpc/main.tf line 37, in resource "aws_vpc" "this":
│   37:   enable_classiclink_dns_support   = var.enable_classiclink_dns_support
│ 
│ An argument named "enable_classiclink_dns_support" is not expected here.
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported argument
│ 
│   on .terraform/modules/vpc/main.tf line 1194, in resource "aws_default_vpc" "this":
│ 1194:   enable_classiclink   = var.default_vpc_enable_classiclink
│ 
│ An argument named "enable_classiclink" is not expected here.
╵
```

Here's my .tf file:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = var.region
}

data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {}

module "vpc" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  version = "2.77.0"
  name = "vpc.rds.multi-az"
  cidr = "10.0.0.0/16"
  azs = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names
  public_subnets = ["10.0.4.0/24", "10.0.5.0/24", "10.0.6.0/24"]
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  enable_dns_support = true
}

resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "rds_multi_az" {
  name = "rds.multi-az"
  subnet_ids = module.vpc.public_subnets
}

resource "aws_security_group" "rds_multi_az" {
  name = "rds.multi-az"
  vpc_id = module.vpc.vpc_id

  ingress {
    from_port = 5432
    to_port = 5432
    protocol = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port = 5432
    to_port = 5432
    protocol = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

resource "aws_db_parameter_group" "rds_multi_az" {
  name = "rds.multi-az"
  family = "postgres14"
  parameter {
    name  = "log_connections"
    value = "1"
  }
}

resource "aws_db_instance" "rds_multi_az" {
  identifier = "rds.multi-az"
  instance_class = "db.t3.micro"
  allocated_storage = 5
  engine = "postgres"
  engine_version = "14.7"
  username = "multiaz"
  password = var.db_password
  db_subnet_group_name = aws_db_subnet_group.rds_multi_az.name
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group]
  parameter_group_name = aws_db_parameter_group.rds_multi_az.name
  publicly_accessible = true
  skip_final_snapshot = true
  multi_az = true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I had not kept the .terraform.lock.hcl file from the repo.  Once that was added `terraform plan` worked.

When I do `terraform init -upgrade` I get the same errors from `terraform plan`.  It looks like hashicorp's example code can't be upgraded.

I've opened an issue [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/learn-terraform-rds/issues/10).

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are using an extremely old version of the `terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws` module. You are using version `2.77.0` and the latest version as of today is `5.2.0`. The AWS VPC feature called "Classic Link" was deprecated and eventually removed by Amazon. The old version of the VPC module you are using is still trying to set that value.

It looks like you do not have a version specified for the Terraform AWS provider, so when you run `terraform init -upgrade` the latest version of the AWS Terraform provider is getting installed. Once that happens you have a versions of the AWS Provider and the VPC module that are simply incompatible with each other.

Running `terraform init -upgrade` just upgrades to the version you have specified in your code. If you have a specific version of a module specified in your code, that command isn't going to upgrade the module past that version. You would need to modify the version specification to something newer, like `5.2.0` and then run `terraform init -upgrade` to upgrade your local copy of the module to that version.

Be aware that upgrading from version 2.x of the module to version 5.x is going to bring in some breaking changes, so you may have other errors to deal with after that.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation.  Hashicorp needs to update their "learning" examples.